# OpenCart payment paypal does not working

Tags: opencart, opencart2.3

I have a problem in my OpenCart E-com website, I added paypal payment in the admin section, but when I try to add a comment about the order while selecting a payment method, I have this issue

[image]

Comment: Would you please translate those strings to English and update your question to include the translations?  This will help folks trying to help you.

Comment: Please specify what error you are getting or what issue you are facing.